# Use relection to get value of an attribute of a property in your object

Tags: reflection, attributes

For example your object is as follows:

```
public class Test{

[Display("**hello world**")]
public string property{}
}
}
```

Ho do I use reflection to get the value of my attribute(Display) which will return "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer dont know if its the best solution?

```
Type t = typeof(T);
var value = t.GetProperties().Select(f=>f.GetCustomAttribute<NamOfAttribute>()).DisplayName
```